# What does this equation mean?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, integration, dimensional-analysis

So I have just entered 11th grade and started limits on my own but my Physics textbook has an equation which I don't understand, I suspect it uses integration which I haven't learned yet. So can someone explain this equation to me:-

The question is:-

> **Find the value of $n$ (by using dimensional analysis):**
>   $$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2ax-x^2}} = a^n \sin^{-1} [\frac{x}{a} -1] $$

The equation looks similar to $$ v^2-u^2 = 2ax $$ But I don't understand what $dx$ means.

Comment: dx is just the variable with which to integrate with respect to. like $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is differentiating y with respect to x. Here, you integrate with respect to x also.

Comment: I think, this is rather a question for math.SE, as it is concerded only with mathematical concepts.

Comment: It would help you would just give a general understanding, you don't have to go too deep.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask the question here : http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c260h1090935_ask_me_your_physics_doubts

Comment: It's a calculus formula. This is not the right place to learn about how calculus works.

Comment: You asked the same question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1296579

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly $a$ has the same dimension of $x$ (see the argument of root or of $\sin^{-1}$) so the left member is dimensionless (ratio between dimension of x: remember that differential dx **count** in dimensional calculus!), and the second member too has to be dimensionless: so n=0.

Answer (score 1):

Integration is finding the area under a curve that isn't necessarily straight. If you have a velocity time graph and find the area under it, this gives you the distance travailed. If you have a acceleration-time graph the area under it is the change in velocity. There are several techniques to integration, which I will not go into here. As mentioned in the comments $dx$ tells you, you are integrating w.r.t. $x$ it is a label rather then a physical quantity in this sense.  When doing dimensional analysis you can simply give the dx a dimension of length then and ignore the integral sign $\int$.